# What spell lets you break an item to return home?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, content-identification

I thought there was a Pathfinder spell that teleported the target safely “home” upon breaking an item and saying a command word. 
The spell caster must prepare the item with the spell in advance. The target who breaks the item could be anyone (i.e. the spell caster could prep an item and give it to someone else for use).

I’ve done a quick search but I cannot find it.

Am I misremembering the spell? Or is it not a Pathfinder spell?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Seek [*refuge*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/refuge/)

That spell is likely the 7th-level cleric spell and 9th-level sorcerer/wizard spell [***refuge***](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/refuge/): "[Y]ou create powerful magic in a specially prepared object [that] contains the power to instantly transport its possessor across any distance within the same plane to your abode.… To make use of the item, the subject speaks the command word at the same time that it rends or breaks the item…."

It's an interesting spell, having a particularly dramatic effect on the plot when a *refuge* object is found secreted among a defeated foe's possessions.

---

***Note:*** The spell refuge *was called* succor *when it was published for* Advanced Dungeon & Dragons *in* [Unearthed Arcana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unearthed_Arcana) *(1985). It kept that name in* Advanced Dungeon & Dragons, 2nd Edition *where that edition's* Player's Handbook *made it a common spell. This reader fully supports the spell's* 3e *(and* Pathfinder *by extension) name change despite believing role-playing games a fantastic vocabulary-building tool.*

Comment: Yeah, that's it. I guess when I was skimming the rules, I misread that as _refuse_. ("I'm not going back there; that place is garbage.")  I have a AD&D book (Unearthed Arcana, maybe?) where I believe a similar spell is called something else; I'll have to  dig the book out of storage and confirm the name is different (or not).

Comment: @StandardEyre After glancing at both the *Priests'* and the *Wizards' Spell Compendiums* (that together I think cover all the *AD&D* and *2e* spells), so far as I can tell the spell *refuge* was concocted for *3e*, although I too seem to (*ahem*) [recall](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/66979/8610) a similar spell.

Comment: @HeyICanChan  Actually, the name just changed between editions.  It used to be called _succor_ and was a PHB spell.

Comment: @Cadrac That had *so* been bothering me! I even have a vivid memory of one DM in the 1990s saying, "And he has a *succor* stick! *Bam!* He's gone!" but I couldn't locate the spell in my *Player's Handbook* for *AD&D*, so I gave up. (I mean, if it's not *there*, it's *nowhere*, amirite?) Turns out the *succor* spell had originally been printed in *Unearthed Arcana* then made its way into the 2nd edition *PH* and the *Wizard's Spell Compendium.* Anyway, enough! Thank you for solving this for me!